# Rails: Redirect from everywhere to root location if not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a simple way to do this?
How do I always trigger this controller, no matter on which page user tries to get?

Comment: are you using any gem for authentications ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `before_filter` to `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :login_required

protected

  def login_required
    redirect_to root_url if not logged_in?
  end
```

Comment: You should accept Yanhao's answer if it solves your problem :)